# How to compare less than or equals with only date of field having timestamp with timezone field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

i am using default `auth_user` table with field `date_joined` as type as `timestamp with time zone`.

All i want to check use the `lte` and `gte` comparison on only its date not with the time and zone.

```
def get_fm_objects(self, filters):
    fm = FacilityManager.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    if filters['from_date']:
        fm = fm.filter(user__date_joined__gte=filters['from_date'])
    if filters['to_date']:
        fm = fm.filter(user__date_joined__lte=filters['to_date'])
    return fm
```

here `FacilityManager` is another model and `filters['from_date']` and `filters['to_date']` are my input dates(it only contains date. eg:2018-1-10).

i have a row in `auth_user` table with `date_joined` as

```
2018-01-11 00:56:39.735756+05:30
```

but when i give From and To date as `2018-01-11`  it returns nothing.

looking for answers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because the time part of the datetime. You can use the `__date` helper in filters. Use it like this:

```
fm.filter(user__date_joined__date__gte=filters['from_date'])
```

And only the Date part of a DateTime will be used.

Answer (score 0):

That is because if you don't specify the time and you compare with a datetime field, the database backend adds 00:00 as the time for comparison. So in your case if you put both the dates as 2018-01-11, it's trying to get values between 2018-01-11 00:00 and 2018-01-11 00:00. Try using 2018-01-12 as the `To` date.